# Как записать в mysql пустой массив без двойных ковычек? Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как мне добавить в mysql массив без двойных ковычек? иногда будет массив с ковычками, а иногда пустота без ковычек. Проект на Laravel

скрин из бд. Без ковычек вариант я вручную добавил
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Контроллер

```html
public function create(Category $category)
    {
        $types = Attribute::typesList();

        return view('admin.adverts.categories.attributes.create', compact('category', 'types'));
    }
```

```html
public function store(Request $request, Category $category)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'type' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', Rule::in(array_keys(Attribute::typesList()))],
            'required' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'variants' => 'nullable|string',
            'sort' => 'required|integer',
        ]);

        $attribute = $category->attributes()->create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'type' => $request['type'],
            'required' => (bool)$request['required'],
            'variants' => array_map('trim', preg_split('#[\r\n]+#', $request['variants'])),
            'sort' => $request['sort'],
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('admin.adverts.categories.attributes.show', [$category, $attribute]);
    }
```

```html
class Attribute extends Model
{
    public const TYPE_STRING = 'string';
    public const TYPE_INTEGER = 'integer';
    public const TYPE_FLOAT = 'float';

    protected $table = 'advert_attributes';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'type', 'required', 'default', 'variants', 'sort'];

    protected $casts = [
        'variants' => 'array',
    ];

    public static function typesList(): array
    {
        return [
            self::TYPE_STRING => 'String',
            self::TYPE_INTEGER => 'Integer',
            self::TYPE_FLOAT => 'Float',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

это JSON (перед записью в БД laravel конвертирует массивы в JSON).

```
var_dump(json_encode(array()));
var_dump(json_encode(array("")));
```

который из этих двух без кавычек, тот и надо записывать

Comment: без ковычек вариант я вручную поставил для наглядности

Comment: что мне необходимо добавить в мой код чтобы без ковычек записалось?

Comment: найти запросы в скрипте, в которых проходят INSERT / UPDATE в таблицу со скрина (Attribute) ( https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserts https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts ), и установить для `variants` значение `!empty(variants) ? variants : array()`

Comment: извиняюсь не весь код для понимания добавил. Добавил код который отвечает за создание в бд. поставил условие http://joxi.ru/LmGgqZ6fwkMppm   

но запись не проходит так как неопределенный аргумент
http://joxi.ru/p27Z6zqiKVOD6m

Comment: отдельно вынести `$request['variants'] = array_map('trim',preg_split('#[\r\n]+#',$request['variants']));` а ключу `variants` в массиве установить `!empty($request['variants']) ? $request['variants'] : array()` (будет выглядеть примерно отак: `$attribute = $category->attributes()->create([...=>...,'variants'=>!empty($request['variants']) ? $request['variants'] : array(),...=>...]);`)

Comment: Ошибки нету все записывается, но все равно с ковычками http://joxi.ru/nAypL7PignZ6e2

Вроде все верно сделал
http://joxi.ru/YmEg1LQfwXg1PA

Comment: `!empty($request['variants']) ? array_diff($request['variants'],array("")) : array()`

Comment: Благодарю спасибо!